# How do I embed an iPython console in a PyQt5 application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, ipython

Is there a way to embed an ipython console into a Qt application easily?  I want create a window with a console that idea has access to the program internals while the program is running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513132/embedding-ipython-qt-console-in-a-pyqt-application ?

Comment: @msw: yup, thanks. I'm unfortunately using pyqt5, so it won't work for me.

Comment: Our examples are for PyQt4, but it should be fairly straightforward to adapt them to Qt 5.