# What's the right way to get an iPython/Jupyter embedded Qt console?

Tags: pyqt, ipython, jupyter

[Embedding IPython Qt console in a PyQt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513132/embedding-ipython-qt-console-in-a-pyqt-application) addresses this question, but the latest answers are from 2014. Apparently things have changed since then, because the following code gives warnings:

```
from IPython.qt.inprocess import QtInProcessKernelManager
from IPython.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget import RichIPythonWidget
```

gives:

```
local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/qt.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.qt` package has been deprecated. You should import from qtconsole instead.
```

But `QtInProcessKernelManager` is only present in `IPython.qt.inprocess`.

What's the non-deprecated way to embed a IPython Qt console in a PyQt application?

Answer (score 1):

Your imports should now look like:

```
from qtconsole.inprocess import QtInProcessKernelManager
from qtconsole.rich_jupyter_widget import RichJupyterWidget
```

For a complete example, check out example from the project github: https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/blob/master/examples/inprocess_qtconsole.py

For more general information, you'll want to check out the [Project Jupyter website](http://jupyter.org/) and/or perform some searches on the ipython --> jupyter transition.