# PySide application with embedded, non-blocking python shell?

Tags: ipython, pyside, jupyter

How do I embed a non-blocking Python shell within a PySide application? It must inherit all active objects and variables. [There is a simple widget available for this in wxPython](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.py.shell.Shell.html) but I cannot find the equivalent widget or approach using Qt/PySide. [An example using PyQt4 and IPython no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513132/embedding-ipython-qt-console-in-a-pyqt-application), perhaps because that functionality is now packaged differently within the [Jupyter Project](https://jupyter.org/). I get the error "ImportError: No module named 'IPython.zmq'". I'm fine with using IPython and Jupyter or not. I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? You know that asking for software recommendations is off-topic on SO, right?

Comment: I've edited my question above. How do I embed a non-blocking Python shell within a PySide application?

Comment: I would imagine that embedding a python shell inside a PySide application would be a common practice since Python is a great application scripting language. Could someone explain how to do it?

Comment: The SO question you linked to gives many examples of how to do it. Not all of them work any more with newer versions of some of the components. So I suppose you will just have to install whatever versions are compatible with your particular setup.

Comment: Your response makes sense and might be my best option. However, I'd like to wait a bit before marking the question answered since I believe Python is widely embedded in applications, including in Qt applications. Perhaps someone can explain how to accomplish this with the most recent version of Qt.

Comment: You can of course use the [code module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#module-code) in the stdlib to write your own embedded interpreter widget. A little web searching found [pynguin](https://bitbucket.org/leeharr/pynguin/src/56353ddb7c05?at=default), a pyqt4 project which includes a python shell based on the `code.InteractiveConsole` class. I also found [qtstuff](https://github.com/JamesRamm/QtStuff/blob/master/build/lib/QtStuff/console.py) and [pythonconsole](https://bitbucket.org/japczynski/pythonconsole.git). I doubt whether any of these do *exactly* what you want, though.

Comment: The QtStuff and PythonConsole both look very helpful. Thank you.