# Embed python as scripting language on my python application

Tags: python, python-embedding

I'm trying to make a python GUI application that handles some sort of data. Then I expect to make the user capable of manipulating that data using python scripts, form within the GUI, using a script interpreter with the data exposed as pre-existing objects. Pretty much like VBA is embedded in MSWord or the way you can embed python on a C application [(see here)](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html).

Is there any technique or library to do this?

Has this been achieved in some project before?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to write a GUI in PyQt, and then embed an iPython console inside the GUI as a GUI widget.

Check out this answer:
[Embedding IPython Qt console in a PyQt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513132/embedding-ipython-qt-console-in-a-pyqt-application)

and a couple other suggestions here:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9508

A different non-PyQt approach is described here:
https://www.pythoncentral.io/embed-interactive-python-interpreter-console/